# Should component update in redux/react-router v4

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-v4

I am passing a property from my "Root" to my a react-route, "Home".

When the "state" (state.loggedIn) of my app changes, "Home" is updated (the appearance changes as expected) but "shouldComponentUpdate" is not called.

I want to use "shouldComponentUpdate" to detect if a property ("loggedIn") changed in the Root, and do some extra work.

```
// Root.js
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Redirect,
  Route,
  Switch} from 'react-router-dom';

...

render() {
  const store = this.props.store;
  const loggedIn = this.state.loggedIn;
  const handleLogin = this.handleLogin;
  const handleLogout = this.handleLogout;

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={
            (props) => (
              <Home
                history={props.history}
                loggedIn={loggedIn}
                handleLogout={handleLogout}/>)} />
          <Route path="/login" component={
            (props) => (
              <Login
                history={props.history}
                handleLogin={handleLogin}/>)} />
         <Route path="/workflow" component={
            loggedIn ?
            ((props) => (
              <Workflows
                history={props.history}
                match={props.match}/>)) :
            ((props) => (
              <Redirect to={
                {
                  pathname: '/',
                  state: {from: props.location},
               }
              }/>)) }/>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
);
```

}

```
// Home.js
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  console.log(nextProps);
  console.log(nextState);
  if(nextProps.loggedIn !== nextState.loggedIn) {
    if(nextState.loggedIn) {
      this.socket.connect();
    } else {
      this.socket.disconnect();
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible the component is being remounted every time rather than just re-rendered?  That would possibly explain why the component is redrawn, but that lifecycle method isn't called.  If you stick a log statement in `componentWillMount()` you'll be able to see if it's being called multiple times.

Comment: Try changing `component` to `render`

Comment: @MattWatson watching the constructor or componentWillMount works - Please submit an answer for me to accept it!

Comment: @Skribja no luck with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your component is being remounted after every state change. That would explain why the component is redrawn, but the lifecyle function `shouldComponentUpdate()` isn't called. If you stick a log statement in `componentWillMount()` you should see it being called multiple times.